# Initializing array to null but failing null comparison

Tags: java, arrays

In the below code, my expectation is if list `readerList.size = 0`, `headerLine` should be `null` inside the method `commonValidation()`. But this is not the case, can anyone tell me why?

```
String[] headerLine = null;

if (readerList != null && readerList.size() != 0){
    headerLine = readerList.get(0);         
}

commonValidation(headerLine, logDTO, hrGroupName, feedFileName);
```

//method definition

```
public void commonValidation(String[] headerLine, TransactionLogDTO logDTO, String hrGroupName, String filename) throws PersistenceException, ServiceException, Exception {
    if ((headerLine == null) || (headerLine.length == 0)){
        logDTO.setGyr("R");

            String subject = MessageWrapper.getMessage("hr.mail.emptyfile.subject");
        String body = MessageWrapper.getMessage("hr.mail.emptyfile.body", filename);

            if (logDTO.getMessage() == null){
                logDTO.setMessage(body);
            }
            else{
                logDTO.setMessage(logDTO.getMessage() + ";" + body);
            }

        logDTO.setIsLogErrorMailSent(Boolean.TRUE);

        sendTransactionLogErrorReport(hrGroupName, subject, body);                  

        throw new Exception(body);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked that the `readerList.size()`? isn't 0 and `readerList` isn't `null`? Otherwise I don't see a problem.

Comment: There is a logical error in this question. From accepted answer it becomes obvious that OP was not interested in "if A then B" violation, but in violation of "if B then A".

Comment: Sorry guys ,actually there was a nullpointer before the method "commonValidation" was called,which resulted in the above scenario.Seeing the answer below i actuall changed my implementation a bit in using existing value from arraylist rather than use a seperate array to capture the data from the list and then use it for validation.So i accepted the below answer.Sorry if i was wrong in accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String[] headerLine = null;` is this a member variable? if yes then make it method local variable.

Also

You can add null elements in ArrayList and size is increased.

```
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    arrayList.add(null);
    System.out.println(arrayList.size());
```

Will Print `1` not `0`.

So check `readerList.get(0)` is `null` or not

Here is the source code of `ArrayList` `add` method

```
 410       public boolean add(E e) {
 411           ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
 412           elementData[size++] = e;
 413           return true;
 414       }
```

If you see there is no check of `null` so you will have to do it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

> But this is not the case, (...)

I don't believe. If `readerList.size() == 0` *headerLine* does not change the value and remains `null`.

Comment: Unless of course another thread changes the value, or other code that the OP is leaving out.